# Create an element of a struct array using struct pointer function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have been trying to write a function with a pointer point to a struct array. After calling it my array should have a new struct element.

This is my function changed by ur guys suggestion

```
void addPic(pic *picture_Record, int picNumber){


pic tmp_Pic;
char tmp_fileName[100];
char tmp_description[100];
char tmp_location[100];

if (picture_Record[picNumber].description ==NULL || picture_Record[picNumber].fileName ==NULL||picture_Record[picNumber].location==NULL)
    return;

printf("Enter: Picture Name, Picture Description, Picture Location, Picture People(int)\n");
scanf("%s%s%s%d",tmp_fileName, tmp_description, tmp_location, &picture_Record[picNumber].peopleCount);  

tmp_Pic.fileName = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp_fileName)+1);
tmp_Pic.description=(char*)malloc(strlen(tmp_description)+1);
tmp_Pic.location = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp_location)+1);
strcpy(tmp_Pic.fileName, tmp_fileName);
strcpy(tmp_Pic.description, tmp_description);
strcpy(tmp_Pic.location, tmp_location);

picture_Record[picNumber] = tmp_Pic;
free(tmp_Pic.fileName);
free(tmp_Pic.description);
free(tmp_Pic.location);
printf("\nInput Done!\n");
```

This is how I call it.

```
 int picNumber = 0
 pic pictureRecord[Maximun_Picture +1]= { "" };

 addPic(&pictureRecord[picNumber], picNumber);
 picNumber++;
 //testing
 printf("%s",pictureRecord[0].location)
```

This is my struct.

```
  typedef struct picture_Data
  {
    char* fileName;
    char* description;
    char* location;
    int peopleCount;
  }pic;
```

It doesn‘t work and printing me Null as th location of the first element. Why? Can somebody help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this line

```
scanf("%s%s%s%d",pic_tmp.fileName, pic_tmp.description, pic_tmp.location, &pic_tmp.peopleCount);
```

assumes that `pic.tmp` has sufficient space allocated for `fileName`, `description`, and `location`. None of that is true, however, because all three fields remain uninitialized.

In order to fix this, change the code to read strings into a temporary buffer, and then copy it into dynamically allocated strings.

Here is how you do it for `fileName`; you need to do the same thing for all three:

```
char tmp_fileName[100];
char tmp_description[100];
char tmp_location[100];
scanf("%99s%99s%99s%d",tmp_fileName, tmp_description, tmp_location, &pic_tmp.peopleCount);
pic_tmp.fileName = malloc(strlen(tmp_fileName)+1);
strcpy(pic_tmp.fileName, tmp_fileName);
...
```

You can copy the `struct` with a single assignment, too:

```
picture_Record[picNumber] = pic_tmp;
```

Don't forget to call `free` on all three members of each `struct` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: +1 and while the OP is at it, lose the whole passed-index thing in the first place. The *caller* should be passing `pictureRecord + picNumber` as the sole parameter to `addPic()`. The temp is not needed at all.

Comment: Sorry to brother again, but my code doesnt work. after inserting the interger the programe will just crush and break down. can u have a look.

Comment: @user3628117 This is because you are freeing the pointers too early. The freeing is supposed to happen last - after you have finished using your record structures. Dereferencing freed pointers is undefined behavior, which often causes crashes.

Answer (score 0):

`You should first have to allocate memory`

```
 void addPic(pic *picture_Record, int picNumber){
 pic pic_tmp;  
 printf("Enter: Picture Name, Picture Description, Picture Location, Picture
 People(int)\n");
 pic_tmp.fileName = (char *)malloc(5);    
 picture_Record[picNumber].fileName = (char *)malloc(5);  
 scanf("%s%d",pic_tmp.fileName, &pic_tmp.peopleCount);  
 printf("\nInput Done!\n");  
 strcpy(picture_Record[picNumber].fileName, pic_tmp.fileName);  
 //picture_Record[picNumber].fileName = pic_tmp.fileName;  
 picture_Record[picNumber].description= pic_tmp.description;  
 picture_Record[picNumber].location = pic_tmp.location;  
 picture_Record[picNumber].peopleCount = pic_tmp.peopleCount;  
 printf("%s,%s",pic_tmp.fileName,picture_Record[picNumber].fileName );  
 }
```